# Não consigo devolver propriedade onclick a um botão com os respectivos parâmetros

Tags: javascript, onclick

Criei um simples jogo da forca, em que dentro de vários temas com várias palavras uma palavra secreta é escolhida aleatoriamente. O utilizador tem ao seu dispor 27 botões, cada uma com uma letra do alfabeto e ao clicar num botão chama uma função (com 2 parâmetros, a letra correspondente e um valor numerico) que verifica se a letra que o utilizador escolheu está em alguma parte da palavra secreta. Quer esteja ou não depois de chamar a função e verificar a propriedade *onclick* é removida.

O meu problema está nos botões que eu tenho para o utilizador escolher um novo tema ou nova palavra, que devolvem a todos os botões do teclado as suas propriedades *onclick* de volta. Eu consigo adicionar de volta a propriedade *onclick* com os parâmetros correspondentes no entanto quando volto a chamar a função verificar() nos botões todos eles agem como se fossem a letra V.

Aqui está a função limpar() que devolve o *onclick* a todos os botões, com os parâmetros correctos.

```
function limpar(){
            nind = 0;
            tentativas = 5;
            ncertas = 0; 
            document.getElementById("mstr").style.display = "";
            document.getElementById("dca").style.display = 'none';
            for(var i = 0; i < 27; i++)
                {
                    tc[i].style.color = '#ffff03';
                    tc[i].onclick = function() { verificar(ar[i], i+1); }; 
                    //Adiciona a propriedade onclick de volta a cada botão, ar[i] é a letra do array correspondente ao botão tc[i] e o i+1 o valor numérico correspondente

                }
            for(var i = 0; i < paltd.length; i++)
                {
                    paltd[i].innerHTML = "-";
                    paltd[i].style.display = 'none';
                }
                document.getElementById("ptnt").innerHTML = tentativas;

        }
```

E aqui está a função verificar que recebe a letra e o número correspondente ao botão clicado.

```
function verificar(b,num){
            //alert(b, num);
            var nerr = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < palavrasecreta.length; i++)
                {
                    if(b == palavrasecreta[i])
                        {
                            paltd[i].innerHTML = b;
                            ncertas += 1;
                            tc[num-1].style.color = '#60ff90';
                        }else{
                            nerr +=1;
                        }       
                } 
            if (nerr == palavrasecreta.length)
                {
                    tentativas -= 1;
                    document.getElementById("ptnt").innerHTML = tentativas;
                    tc[num-1].style.color = '#773333';
                }
            //alert(ncertas);
            tc[num-1].onclick = function(){};
            verificarjogo(ncertas);

        }
```

O meu problema é que por alguma razão a função verificar() está sempre a verificar como se tivesse clicado no botão da letra V, não interessa qual botão eu clique. Ao inspeccionar elemento vejo que todos os botões tem os seus respectivos parâmetros, no entanto ao clicar chamam sempre a função verificar() com os parâmetros V e 24.
Na primeira vez que o jogo corre tudo dá certo, isto só acontece após chamar a função limpar que faz um "reset" ao jogo, devolvendo a cada botão a sua propriedade onclick.

Edit: Esqueci me de mencionar que o teclado são botões da mesma classe numa página html dispostos em formato qwerty, e cada número corresponde á sua posição na classe. V por exemplo é o 24º botão (23 na classe)

Comment: Também experimentei utilizar *setAttribute* para definir a propriedade *onclick* para "" e posteriormente para os parâmetros correctos e os valores passaram de V e 24 para Y e 6 uma vez e depois U e 7 para tudo o resto.

Answer (score 0):

Acabei por resolver o problema utilizando o atributo *disable* , definindo na função verificar() o disable para "", e na função limpar() para *false*

```
function limpar(){
            nind = 0;
            tentativas = 5;
            ncertas = 0; 
            document.getElementById("mstr").style.display = "";
            document.getElementById("dca").style.display = 'none';
            for(var i = 0; i < 27; i++)
                {
                    tc[i].style.color = '#ffff03';
                    tc[i].disabled = false;
                }
            for(var i = 0; i < paltd.length; i++)
                {
                    paltd[i].innerHTML = "-";
                    paltd[i].style.display = 'none';
                }
                document.getElementById("ptnt").innerHTML = tentativas;

        }




function verificar(b,num){
            //alert(b);
            //alert(num);
            var nerr = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < palavrasecreta.length; i++)
                {
                    if(b == palavrasecreta[i])
                        {
                            paltd[i].innerHTML = b;
                            ncertas += 1;
                            tc[num-1].style.color = '#60ff90';
                        }else{
                            nerr +=1;
                        }       
                } 
            if (nerr == palavrasecreta.length)
                {
                    tentativas -= 1;
                    document.getElementById("ptnt").innerHTML = tentativas;
                    tc[num-1].style.color = '#773333';
                }
            //alert(ncertas);
            tc[num-1].setAttribute("disabled", "");
            verificarjogo(ncertas);

        }
```